# SQL - I need to find patients that have received an x number of procedures in y amount of time

Tags: sql

I am needing to do some analysis of healthcare patients that have received a certain drug, I need to know for patients that received that drug, how many times have they received it, and for how long have they been receiving treatment after they first received a drug.

The question I'm being asked is to find patients with at least 4 months total treatment (including follow ups) that have received the drug in a minimum of 2 separate visits.

[image: ![enter image description here]

My table looks like the above, in a SQL database, so patient 12345 would qualify, I just don't know how to write the query to include the criteria of >= 4 months treatment, and >= 2 separate drug treatments, and return the patient's IDs.

Comment: Hi - 1) please don’t use images, use editable text that someone can copy 2) provide table definitions 3) provide sample data 4) provide the result that you want to achieve based on your sample data 5) provide the SQL you’ve managed to write on your own

Comment: Also note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.

Comment: If you can write a query to output those 4 columns then it will be easy to copy/paste that data into your question. Or create a "fiddle" like this:  
 https://dbfiddle.uk/Xbawhz8w   **nb** those dates in the image: are they all dates in January (dd/mm/yyyy) or that weird way where months are shown first?

Comment: I've posted a possible answer based on the extremely limited information in your question, but I suggest you check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's also helpful if you provide the exact RDBMS you're using - SQL Server, MySQL, Sybase, or whatever else you might be working with.

Answer (score 0):

Using your (quite limited) sample data:

```
create table #data
(
    Patient_ID int,
    Visit_Id int,
    [Procedure] varchar(9),
    [Date of service] date
)

insert into #data values
(12345,1111,'Drug A','2023-01-01'),
(12345,1112,'Follow Up','2023-02-01'),
(12345,1113,'Drug A','2023-04-01'),
(12345,1114,'Follow Up','2023-07-01');
```

You can use a CTE to get the first and last visits and the number of drug treatments, then select from that cte the results you want:

```
with cte as
(
    select
        p1.Patient_ID,
        min([Date of service]) as firstVisit,
        max([Date of service]) as lastVisit,
        sum(case when p1.[Procedure] like 'Drug %' then 1 else 0 end) as numDrugTreatments
    from #data p1
    group by Patient_ID
)

select * 
from cte
where datediff(month,firstVisit,lastVisit) >= 4
and numDrugTreatments >= 2
```

In the case of your example data, this will of course just return a single record, but it should work on your (presumably) larger actual data set.